# Wait message before D3 force layout renders

Tags: javascript, extjs, d3.js, force-layout

I have implemented force layout using d3.js. However the layout changes according to the user selection in the UI which makes a new call to the server and fetches new data and again draws a force layout. Until then user has to wait. Is there a way we can show a wait message to the user before the graph loads. Also this layout is a part of the extjs component so the wait message needs to be applied only to that specific component. I would have used Ext js wait message but I don't have events to listen to hide and show the wait message as graph rendering is independent of ext js. I researched a lot and could not find any such feature in d3.js. But there should be some workaround I am just not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward to do, although D3 doesn't provide any explicit functionality for it. When the user makes a selection and you send the asynchronous request for more data, enable the "wait" dialog. Then, inside the function that handles the received data, disable it. That's it. In code, it would look something like this.

```
userSelector.on("click", function() {
  enableWaitDialog();
  d3.json("newjson.json", function(error, data) {
    // do something with the new JSON
    disableWaitDialog();
  });
});
```